# Can't set the selected value using jquery chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using the chosen plugin from jquery and I want to get the selected value option from my select menu. In my source code, it shows the option that was select previously, from the database. But the selected option doesn't appear.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedDistrict = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#class_of_my_select').chosen();
    $("#class_of_my_select").change(function () {
        selectedDistrict = $("#class_of_my_select").val();
        $("#class_of_my_select").trigger("chosen:updated").val(selectedDistrict);  
    });
});
```

And this is my form:

form.php

```
<select  style="width: 390px;display: inline-block;" class="input-sm form-control" name="class_of_my_select" id="class_of_my_select"  type="text">
     <option value=""></option>

     <?php foreach ($list as $key){ ?>

     <option value="<? echo $key->id; ?>" ><? echo $key->name; ?></option>

     <?}?>
```

Comment: Why do you need to set the value? That's the value it already has.

Comment: This is a edit form. I need the value to appear in the select menu.

Comment: This code runs when the user selects something from the menu. You don't need to do anything to make the value appear, it happens automatically when they do that.

Comment: You only need to use `.trigger("chosen:updated")` if you change the value using JavaScript, not by the user selecting from the menu.

Comment: This isn't working for me. The menu is working like it was a insert form.